# How to have the dataValidation list updated via Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know this is a bit messy, but the question here is the following:
The code below is running on a trigger and it's supposed to give me a list of the items in the range specified below, but it only happens when I'm on the cell stated in the conditions and I have to press delete or edit it somehow to get the list updated.
How would I go about having it automatically updated no matter where I am n the sheet?

```
function setItemList(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var arquivoItens = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ArquivoItens');
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var versao = ss.getRange("AD4");
  var itemList = arquivoItens.getRange('B2:B');

  if(ss.getSheetName() === "EditarItem" && activeCell.getColumn() == 24 && activeCell.getRow() == 4){
    var arrayValues = itemList.getValues();  
    var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(arrayValues);
    activeCell.setDataValidation(rangeRule);
    Logger.log(itemList);
   }
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try removing the a row and column conditions. I assume this is an on edit trigger and you would save some time in your function if you would utilize the event object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create time driven triggers like:

[image: time trigger]

I would recommend you to change the`getActiveSpreadsheet()` for [`openById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)

Answer (score 0):

It is working that way because that is what's written in the code. Your code explicitly says that it should only execute if the activeCell is "X4". So I am not sure if you really need that, if yes, please let us know what are you trying to achieve there, else remove that part like here.

```
function setItemList(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var arquivoItens = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ArquivoItens');
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var versao = ss.getRange("AD4");
  var itemList = arquivoItens.getRange('B2:B');

  if(ss.getSheetName() === "EditarItem"){
    var arrayValues = itemList.getValues();  
    var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(arrayValues);
    activeCell.setDataValidation(rangeRule);
    Logger.log(itemList);
   }
  }
```

Also you have not mentioned on which trigger it should work, because if it is a time based trigger then there is no point in using Activesheet or ActiveCell references.